# Building a grid framework with inline-block's

Tags: css, frameworks, grid

I'm about to update http://getcrow.eu and have one "issue" to solve that would make the framework everything I always wanted it to be.

Important to know:
Crow does not use `tables`, `absolute positioning`, `floats` or `clearfix`'es and it should stay that way.

We know that putting inline-blocks next to each other like so:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Block 1</div>
  <div>Block 2</div>
  <div>Block 3</div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.parent {
  > div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Creates white-spaces between the blocks. We also know there's a handful of solutions to prevent the white-spaces from creating space, which is highly required if creating a grid framework with this method.

Beneath I list the methods that I'm aware of and why I don't want to/can't use them:

(SKIP IF YOU WANT TO GET TO THE QUESTION)

---

1. Comments in the HTML inbetween children div's.
   No-go because: it creates ugly HTML that the developer, using crow, must be aware of and work with.
2. Breaking lines at the end of children tags/ not using closing tags.
   No-go because: same as above
3. Using minus (-) margins on .parent-wrapper.
   No-go because: specified margins depends on document font size which mean the grid could break in responsive markup where html { font-size:{X}px; } changes.
4. Setting 0px font-size to .parent and "reset" the font size on children (this is the method I'm currently using).
   No-go because: I don't want the developer using crow to force-set the children. I just want the inheritance to be natural without a grid that's setting the font size downwards for me.
5. Using Javascript to remove all white-spaces from .crow elements.
   No-go because: I want the framework to be pure CSS and no js. This could also "flick" the DOM after pageload if user has bad connection.
6. Loading a font with font-family on .parent that has no white spaces.
   No-go because: loading in an extra font just to get the grid framework is just wrong. Especially as you have to download extra files (font-files) and declare fallbacks for all browsers.
7. Using letter-spacing -{X}px on .parent.
   No-go because: same as .3 (see above)
8. Using flex box.
   No-go because: the framework focuses on vertical centering (if desired) and flex box lives it own life when it comes to that. I'm also making sure the grid is supporting IE8 which it does today.

---

So basically I'm searching for a - unknown/not yet discovered/way that I'm not aware of - for removing white spaces in between inline-blocks. I want it to be pure CSS. If you have a method that you know of/think would work - I can try it on different browsers.

Resolving this would surely make Crow the best grid framework. I'm already using it for various websites and I can tell that the possibilites are many when given the ability to easily position elements center vertically.

Sidenote:
Marking up the DOM like so: `<div class="parent"><div>Block 1</div><div>Block 2</div></div>` does the job just like I want it to. But that would require the developer using Crow to mark it up that way. And I don't want to rely on a framework creating that HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InuitCSS (my choice of framework lately) uses a similar system. As wonderful as the use of `display: inline-block;` is in a grid system, it does appear that the whitespace issue, is an inherent one; with little chance of resolution beyond the current workarounds.

I agree that the use of comments or closing tags does introduce some issues with CMS entries, and a certain amount of mental overhead for the developers involved; but not an unmanageable amount.

If you want to have a look at Inuit's grids I would recommend it's GitHub found here:
https://github.com/inuitcss

I would also advise reading this issue, in-which Inuit's creator; Harry Roberts, weighs in on the various solutions this problem. Whilst it may not tell you anything you don't already know, it is an interesting (if outdated) discussion on the matter.

https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css/issues/170

I know that the above may not solve your issue, or even shed any light on the matter, but I hope it can be of use.

Comment: Thank you very much Jamie! They are using the "no white space" method of getting "no white space" :) Though I found one comment saying you can set `font-size: initial;` on .parent children which I knew, which breakes in IE - but for IE you got  `font-size: medium;` which solves that.

Even though removing the actual white space may be the better solution, this is still way better than my current solution with "resetting the font size on children to what DOM had previously" since that would require the developer to keep track of/know that size.

I learned something today thanks to you :)

Comment: I'm also going to download inuitcss and check it out for inspiration.

Comment: Glad I was of help! Definitely explore Inuit a little. It's creator, Harry; really keeps it and his work quite understated, but certainly deserves far wider usage and attention that it gets.

Comment: And that is because inline-block rules! You have much more control over your content and can do much more awesome stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a float is your best option.

```
.parent div {
    float: left;
}
```

Following your comments below you could use a negative margin.

```
.parent div {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

But this may change browser to browser.

Comment: Hey James thank you for your answer. I just added a text describing what can't/should not be used.

A grid should, in my opinion, not rely on floats to align correctly - since floats are meant to be used to pull things to the left/right. My framework is working from "the middle" in everything it does, and floats does not.

I like floats, but not for grid frameworks. It's better of pushing some image into text or aligning some element to the far right in a wrapper.

Comment: Not a problem but it seems as though you're applying a lot of unnecessary constraints on yourself. Good luck though!

Comment: I have been using twitter bootstrap for ~10 websites and foundation framework for 1. If I can get this right I will never use those again if required.

To align something center-center with Crow you can simply type <div class="crow"><div>I'm in center</div></div>. Only that feature alone makes Crow superior :)

Comment: I played around with -{X}px margins, but they're not always 100% precise. And if you change the HTML font-size, which is the best practice for responsive font-sizing, the grid breaks.

When I researched the issue about white spaces inbetween inline-blocks I found many examples of -{X}px margins which actually does not even work when watching it on retina screens (the author of the code claims it works, but with retina it doesn't. The layout is correct, but you can see 0.5px space inbewteen)